# Dynamically create DIV children and add/populate their value

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, dynamic-content

Could you please help make it work, I am trying to dynamically create the elements

inside  and populate/add into each element of the DIV dynamic value that would be returned from the database by the server function. Maybe there is a better way to do this? But i don't know any other options.

Here is the code but it is not working, the console displays the error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null):

```
//This is the server side code that returns the data, it works fine, have checked it;
        function getReadyLine() {
            var rawData = sheetMAT.getRange(3, 2, sheetMAT.getLastRow() - 2, 5).getValues();
            for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {
                if (rawData[i][3] === "A Ready Line" && rawData[i][4] === "ATY") {
                    temp1 = ' ' + data[i][0];
                    temp2.push(data[i][1], temp1);
                    dataReadyLine.push(temp2);
                    temp1 = '';
                    temp2 = [];
                }
            }
            return dataReadyLine;
        }

        //This is the client side code that should populate the innerHTML of the DIV template that is shown below;
        setInterval(function() {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(data) {
                var temp3 = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    temp3 = 'p' + data[i] + '/p';
                    document.getElementById("#item1").innerHTML = temp3;
                    temp3 = '';
                }
            }).getReadyLine();
        }, 10000);
    </script>

    //This is the DIV where I want to embed, display all the content/data returned from the server-side with the function getReadyLine();
    <div class="col-sm-3 col1">
        <h1 id="readyLine">Ready Line,
            <?= getCountReadyLine() ?> items</h1>
        <div class="item1" id="item1">
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: Print Screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("#item1").innerHTML = temp3;
```

Should be:

```
document.getElementById("item1").innerHTML = temp3;
```

The `#` should not be included while using `getElementById()` function.